# .NET: file uploading to server using http

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-mvc, httpclient, webclient

I have a running-state `.php` script that hits a URL and uploads a single/multiple files `.csv` type with a unique `token` sent with them (in the body AFAIK). Below is the working snippet:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$ch = curl_init('http://demo.schooling.net/school/attendance');

$DirPath = "E:/Uploads/";

$ZKFiles=array();

if ($dh = opendir($DirPath)) 
{
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) 
    {
        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') 
        {
            continue;
        }
        $ZKFiles[]='@'.$DirPath.$file;       
    }
    closedir($dh);
}
if(!empty($ZKFiles))
{
    // Assign POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,false);
    curl_setopt_custom_postfields($ch, array('Files[]'=>$ZKFiles,'token'=>'fe60313b0edfdfaf757f9744815454545'));
    // Execute the handle
    $execResult=curl_exec($ch);
    if($execResult=== false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
        echo $execResult;
    }

}


function curl_setopt_custom_postfields($ch, $postfields, $headers = null) {
    $algos = hash_algos();
    $hashAlgo = null;
    foreach ( array('sha1', 'md5') as $preferred ) {
        if ( in_array($preferred, $algos) ) {
            $hashAlgo = $preferred;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( $hashAlgo === null ) { list($hashAlgo) = $algos; }
    $boundary =
        '----------------------------' .
        substr(hash($hashAlgo, 'cURL-php-multiple-value-same-key-support' . microtime()), 0, 12);

    $body = array();
    $crlf = "\r\n";
    $fields = array();
    foreach ( $postfields as $key => $value ) {
        if ( is_array($value) ) {
            foreach ( $value as $v ) {
                $fields[] = array($key, $v);
            }
        } else {
            $fields[] = array($key, $value);
        }
    }

    //print_r($fields);die();
    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        list($key, $value) = $field;
        if ( strpos($value, '@') === 0 ) {
            preg_match('/^@(.*?)$/', $value, $matches);
            list($dummy, $filename) = $matches;
            $body[] = '--' . $boundary;
            $body[] = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' . $key . '"; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"';
            $body[] = 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream';
            $body[] = '';
            $body[] = file_get_contents($filename);
        } else {
            $body[] = '--' . $boundary;
            $body[] = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' . $key . '"';
            $body[] = '';
            $body[] = $value;
        }
    }
    $body[] = '--' . $boundary . '--';
    $body[] = '';
    //print_r($body);die();
    $contentType = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $boundary;
    $content = join($crlf, $body);
    $contentLength = strlen($content);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Length: ' . $contentLength,
        'Expect: 100-continue',
        'Content-Type: ' . $contentType,
    ));
    //echo $content;die();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
}
?>
```

To accomplish this in .NET, What I've tried so far (all the possible ways)

First Approach (using `WebClient`):

```
[HttpPost]
public void SendFiles()
{
    string fileToUpload = @"E:\Uploads\demo.csv";
    string url ="http://demo.schooling.net/school/attendance";
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        //sending token and then uplaoding file
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection postData =
                        new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection()
        {
            { "token", "fe60313b0edfdfaf757f9744815454545" }
        };
        string pagesource = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(url, "POST", postData));

        //string authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("fe60313b0edfdfaf757f9744815454545"));
        client.Headers["token"] = "fe60313b0edfdfaf757f9744815454545";
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
        byte[] result = client.UploadFile(url, fileToUpload);
        string responseAsString = Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
    }
}
```

This did not send the token to the url, hence the page gets redirected to login page.

Second Approach (using `.NET MultipartDataContent`)

```
string fileUpload = @"E:\Uploads\demo.csv";
string uri = "http://demo.schooling.net/school/attendance";
//Using built-in MultipartFormDataContent
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
MultipartFormDataContent form1 = new MultipartFormDataContent();
FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileUpload);
var streamContent = new StreamContent(fs);

var Content = new ByteArrayContent(streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
//Add token here first
form1.Add(new StringContent("fe60313b0edfdfaf757f9744815454545"), "token");
form1.Add(Content, "csv", Path.GetFileName(fileUpload));
var response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, form1).Result;
```

This failed and so it led me to the third try. (no token was sent)

Third Approach (using cutom `MultipartForm` described [here](https://dzimchuk.net/uploading-a-file-over-http-in-net/))

```
//Using Custom MultipartForm
MultipartForm form = new MultipartForm(url);
form.SetField("token", "fe60313b0edfdfaf757f9744815454545");

form.SendFile(@"E:\Uploads\demo.csv");
```

MultiPartForm.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;

namespace Helpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Allow the transfer of data files using the W3C's specification
    /// for HTTP multipart form data. Microsoft's version has a bug
    /// where it does not format the ending boundary correctly.
    /// Original version written by Gregory Prentice : gregoryp@norvanco.com
    /// See: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/gregoryprentice/DotNetBugs12062005230632PM/DotNetBugs.aspx
    /// </summary>
    public class MultipartForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Holds any form fields and values that you
        /// wish to transfer with your data.
        /// </summary>
        private Hashtable coFormFields;

        /// <summary>
        /// Used mainly to avoid passing parameters to other routines.
        /// Could have been local to sendFile().
        /// </summary>
        protected HttpWebRequest coRequest;

        /// <summary>
        /// Used if we are testing and want to output the raw
        /// request, minus http headers, out to a file.
        /// </summary>
        private Stream coFileStream;

        /// <summary>
        /// Difined to build the form field data that is being
        /// passed along with the request.
        /// </summary>
        private static string CONTENT_DISP = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=";

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows you to specify the specific version of HTTP to use for uploads.
        /// The dot NET stuff currently does not allow you to remove the continue-100 header
        /// from 1.1 and 1.0 currently has a bug in it where it adds the continue-100. MS
        /// has sent a patch to remove the continue-100 in HTTP 1.0.
        /// </summary>
        public Version TransferHttpVersion { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to change the content type of the file being sent.
        /// Currently defaults to: text/xml. Other options are
        /// text/plain or binary
        /// </summary>
        public string FileContentType { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize our class for use to send data files.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">The web address of the recipient of the data transfer.</param>
        public MultipartForm(string url)
        {
            URL = url;
            coFormFields = new Hashtable();
            ResponseText = new StringBuilder();
            BufferSize = 1024 * 10;
            BeginBoundary = "ou812--------------8c405ee4e38917c";
            TransferHttpVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            //FileContentType = "text/xml";
            FileContentType = "text/csv";
        }
        //---------- BEGIN PROPERTIES SECTION ----------
        private string _BeginBoundary;
        /// <summary>
        /// The string that defines the begining boundary of
        /// our multipart transfer as defined in the w3c specs.
        /// This method also sets the Content and Ending
        /// boundaries as defined by the w3c specs.
        /// </summary>
        public string BeginBoundary
        {
            get { return _BeginBoundary; }
            set
            {
                _BeginBoundary = value;
                ContentBoundary = "--" + BeginBoundary;
                EndingBoundary = ContentBoundary + "--";
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The string that defines the content boundary of
        /// our multipart transfer as defined in the w3c specs.
        /// </summary>
        protected string ContentBoundary { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The string that defines the ending boundary of
        /// our multipart transfer as defined in the w3c specs.
        /// </summary>
        protected string EndingBoundary { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The data returned to us after the transfer is completed.
        /// </summary>
        public StringBuilder ResponseText { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The web address of the recipient of the transfer.
        /// </summary>
        public string URL { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows us to determine the size of the buffer used
        /// to send a piece of the file at a time out the IO
        /// stream. Defaults to 1024 * 10.
        /// </summary>
        public int BufferSize { get; set; }

        //---------- END PROPERTIES SECTION ----------

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to signal we want the output to go to a
        /// text file verses being transfered to a URL.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path"></param>
        public void SetFilename(string path)
        {
            coFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Allows you to add some additional field data to be
        /// sent along with the transfer. This is usually used
        /// for things like userid and password to validate the
        /// transfer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The form field name</param>
        /// <param name="str">The form field value</param>
        public void SetField(string key, string str)
        {
            coFormFields[key] = str;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if we have a file stream set, and returns either
        /// the HttpWebRequest stream of the file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual Stream GetStream()
        {
            Stream stream;
            if (null == coFileStream)
                stream = coRequest.GetRequestStream();
            else
                stream = coFileStream;
            return stream;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Here we actually make the request to the web server and
        /// retrieve it's response into a text buffer.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void GetResponse()
        {
            if (null == coFileStream)
            {
                Stream stream;
                WebResponse response;
                try
                {
                    response = coRequest.GetResponse();
                }
                catch (WebException web)
                {
                    response = web.Response;
                }
                if (null != response)
                {
                    stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                    string str;
                    ResponseText.Length = 0;
                    while ((str = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        ResponseText.Append(str);
                    response.Close();
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("MultipartForm: Error retrieving server response");
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Transmits a file to the web server stated in the
        /// URL property. You may call this several times and it
        /// will use the values previously set for fields and URL.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename">The full path of file being transfered.</param>
        public void SendFile(string filename)
        {
            // The live of this object is only good during
            // this function. Used mainly to avoid passing
            // around parameters to other functions.
            coRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            // Set use HTTP 1.0 or 1.1.
            coRequest.ProtocolVersion = TransferHttpVersion;
            coRequest.Method = "POST";
            coRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + BeginBoundary;
            coRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            coRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            string strFields = GetFormfields();
            string strFileHdr = GetFileheader(filename);
            string strFileTlr = GetFiletrailer();
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(filename);
            coRequest.ContentLength = strFields.Length +
              strFileHdr.Length +
              strFileTlr.Length +
              info.Length;
            System.IO.Stream io;
            io = GetStream();
            WriteString(io, strFields);
            WriteString(io, strFileHdr);
            this.WriteFile(io, filename);
            WriteString(io, strFileTlr);
            GetResponse();
            io.Close();
            // End the life time of this request object.
            coRequest = null;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Mainly used to turn the string into a byte buffer and then
        /// write it to our IO stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stream">The io stream for output.</param>
        /// <param name="str">The data to write.</param>
        public void WriteString(Stream stream, string str)
        {
            byte[] postData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
            stream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Builds the proper format of the multipart data that
        /// contains the form fields and their respective values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The data to send in the multipart upload.</returns>
        public string GetFormfields()
        {
            string str = "";
            IDictionaryEnumerator myEnumerator = coFormFields.GetEnumerator();
            while (myEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                str += ContentBoundary + "\r\n" +
                  CONTENT_DISP + '"' + myEnumerator.Key + "\"\r\n\r\n" +
                  myEnumerator.Value + "\r\n";
            }
            return str;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the proper content information for the
        /// file we are sending.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Hits Patel reported a bug when used with ActiveFile.
        /// Added semicolon after sendfile to resolve that issue.
        /// Tested for compatibility with IIS 5.0 and Java.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="filename"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string GetFileheader(string filename)
        {
            return ContentBoundary + "\r\n" +
              CONTENT_DISP +
              "\"sendfile\"; filename=\"" +
              Path.GetFileName(filename) + "\"\r\n" +
              "Content-type: " + FileContentType + "\r\n\r\n";
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the proper ending boundary for the multipart upload.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The ending boundary.</returns>
        public string GetFiletrailer()
        {
            return "\r\n" + EndingBoundary;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Reads in the file a chunck at a time then sends it to the
        /// output stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stream">The io stream to write the file to.</param>
        /// <param name="filename">The name of the file to transfer.</param>
        public void WriteFile(Stream stream, string filename)
        {
            using (FileStream readIn = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                readIn.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // move to the start of the file
                byte[] fileData = new byte[BufferSize];
                int bytes;
                while ((bytes = readIn.Read(fileData, 0, BufferSize)) > 0)
                {
                    // read the file data and send a chunk at a time
                    stream.Write(fileData, 0, bytes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With no luck but much tolerance, comes the fourth attempt (no token was sent in this approach either)

Fourth Approach (using `HttpClient`)

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        var values = new[]
        {

    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", "fe60313b0edfdfaf757f9744815454545")
     //other values
};

        foreach (var keyValuePair in values)
        {
            multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value),
                String.Format("\"{0}\"", keyValuePair.Key));
        }

        multipartFormDataContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\\Uploads\\demo.csv")),
            '"' + "File" + '"',
            '"' + "democollege.csv" + '"');
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("token", "fe60313b0edfdfaf757f9744815454545");
        var requestUri = "http://demo.schooling.net/school/attendance";
        var result = client.PostAsync(requestUri, multipartFormDataContent).Result;
    }
}
```

This shot me down as well, again no token and eventually no file was uploaded

Fifth Approach (using `HttpWebRequest`)

```
   public static void HttpUploadFile(string url, string file, string paramName, string contentType, NameValueCollection nvc)
        {
            string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
            byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

            HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            wr.Method = "POST";
            wr.KeepAlive = true;
            wr.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
           // wr.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");
            wr.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + "fe60313b0edfdfaf757f9744815454545");
            wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();
            string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";
            foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
            {
                rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
                string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
                byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
                rs.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
            }
            rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
            string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName, file, contentType);
            byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
            rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            fileStream.Close();
            byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
            rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
            rs.Close();
            WebResponse wresp = null;
            try
            {
                wresp = wr.GetResponse();
                Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
                var result = reader2.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               // System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error occurred while converting file", "Error!");
                if (wresp != null)
                {
                    wresp.Close();
                    wresp = null;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                wr = null;
            }
        }
```

and then calling that method:

```
string fileToUpload = @"E:\Uploads\demo.csv";
                string url = "http://demo.schooling.net/school/attendance";
                NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
                nvc.Add("token", "fe60313b0edfdfaf757f9744815454545");
                HttpUploadFile(url, fileToUpload, "file", "text/csv", nvc);
```

This failed as well, even though I am getting the form data. (picture attached, using one of the attempts above)
[image]

By adding this line in the `PHP` script:

```
 ...$body[] = '';
    print_r($body);die();
```

I can see this in the browser:

```
Array ( [0] => Array 
( [0] => Files[] 
[1] => @E:/Uploads/demo.csv ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => token 
[1] => fe60313b0edfdfaf757f9744815454545) )
```

Add the line below in the php script:

```
print_r($body); die();
```

at the end of the `function curl_setopt_custom_postfields($ch, $postfields, $headers = null);` function I could see this on the browser:

```
Array ( [0] => ------------------------------3c935d382987 
[1] => Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Files[]"; filename="demo.csv" 
[2] => Content-Type: application/octet-stream 
[3] => 
[4] => No,Name,Time,Verify,Mach,Ex,checktype,sid,code,Date 22364,22364,12/8/2017 10:28,Fingerpint,democollege-1-1,,I,1,0,12/8/2017 22365,22365,12/8/2017 9:29,Fingerpint,democollege-1-1,,I,1,0,12/8/2017 22366,22366,12/8/2017 10:59,Fingerpint,democollege-1-1,,I,1,0,12/8/2017 22369,22369,12/8/2017 11:58,Fingerpint,democollege-1-1,,I,1,0,12/8/2017 22364,22364,11/7/2017 10:28,Fingerpint,democollege-1-1,,I,1,0,11/7/2017 22365,22365,11/7/2017 9:29,Fingerpint,democollege-1-1,,I,1,0,11/7/2017 22366,22366,11/7/2018 10:59,Fingerpint,democollege-1-1,,I,1,0,11/7/2017 22369,22369,11/7/2018 11:58,Fingerpint,democollege-1-1,,I,1,0,11/7/2017 
[5] => ------------------------------3c935d382987 
[6] => Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token" 
[7] => 
[8] => fe60313b0edfdfaf757f9744815454545
[9] => ------------------------------3c935d382987-- 
[10] => )
```

Fiddler:

[image]

Comment: WebClient should work fine to communicate with any HTTP server. It doesn't mean it will do what you want, but the token header should at least navigate. Have you used a tool such as fiddler to check what's going on on the wire?

Comment: @SimonMourier took me an hour to get my hands on fiddler, I attached a picture above. It does not send the header as well. (hence the url redirects to login page) if the token is received & authenticated, it displays a message like "Data uploaded".

Comment: You should be looking at the 'inspectors' tab. I've tested your code and it does send a token value (*not* a header, but a form value)

Comment: @SimonMourier can we continue this in the chat?

Comment: Your PHP script is NOT sending a token either in Header or in the Body of the HTTP request. The $headers variable that's being used to pass the token to  curl_setopt_custom_postfields function is not used in that function at all.

Comment: @NGambit I noticed that as well but the files do not get uploaded if the token isn't received or is incorrect on the server side. It then redirects it to the login page instead of displaying the "uploaded successfully" message.

Comment: Well if it's true that the server side needs a token then your php script can't be working as you claim it to be

Comment: Unless you're passing the token in some other way. The only way I can think of that happening is if you're passing the token in the text of the files you're uploading and the server side somehow parses it to determine the response to the http request

Comment: @NGambit that is the weird part, I tried to remove/change the token from my php script (and it does not upload). If I give it the correct token (as given by the senior dev), it works fine.

Answer (score 6):

**.Net Web Api File; Upload,Download, Image Review and SendCloud services**

*Web.config*

```
<appSettings>

 <!--FileService-->
    <add key="ftpUserName" value="fooUserName" />
    <add key="ftpPassword" value="fooPass" />

<!--FileController-->
    <add key="fileServiceLocalPath" value="~/App_Data/Upload" />
    <add key="fileServiceStoragePath" value="fooFtpAddress" />
    <add key="useCloud" value="false" />

</appSettings>
```

File Controller with Authentication

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/File")]

 public class FileController : ApiController
    {
        IFileService fileService = null;
        public FileController(IFileService _fileService)
        {
            fileService = _fileService;
        }

        [Route("Upload"), HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload()
        {
            #region Condition

            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType, Messages.FUW0001);
            #endregion

            /// `localPath` and `useCloud` is get from Web.Config.
            string localPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileServiceLocalPath"]);
            bool useCloud = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["useCloud"]);

            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(localPath);

            try
            {
                /// Loads the files into the local storage.
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

                /// Check is exist valid file.
                if (provider.FileData.Count == 0)
                    return BadRequest(Messages.FUE0001 /*Message Type FUE001 = File Not Found */);

                IList<FileDto> modelList = new List<FileDto>();

                foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
                {
                    string originalName = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
                    if (originalName.StartsWith("\"") && originalName.EndsWith("\""))
                    {
                        originalName = originalName.Trim('"');
                    }
                    if (originalName.Contains(@"/") || originalName.Contains(@"\"))
                    {
                        originalName = Path.GetFileName(originalName);
                    }

                    /// File information storage my database.
                    FileDto fileDto = new FileDto
                    {
                        OriginalName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalName),
                        StorageName = Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName),
                        Extension = Path.GetExtension(originalName).ToLower().Replace(".", ""),
                        Size = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName).Length
                    };

                    modelList.Add(fileDto);
                }

                if (useCloud)
                    await fileService.SendCloud(modelList,localPath);

                await fileService.Add(modelList, IdentityClaimsValues.UserID<Guid>());

                return Ok(Messages.Ok);
            }
            catch (Exception exMessage)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, exMessage);
            }
        }

    [   Route("Download"), HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Download(Guid id)
        {
            /// Get file information my database
            var model = await fileService.GetByID(id);

            if (model == null)
                return BadRequest();

            /// `localPath` is get from Web.Config.
            string localPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileServiceLocalPath"]);

            string root = localPath + "\\" + model.StorageName;

            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(root);
            var stream = new MemoryStream(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);

            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray())
            };

            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = model.OriginalName + "." + model.Extension,
                    Size=model.Size
                };

            response.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            IHttpActionResult result = ResponseMessage(response);
            return result;
        }

        [Route("ImageReview"), HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ImageReview(Guid id)
        {
            /// Get file information my database
            var model = await fileService.GetByID(id);

            if (model == null)
                return BadRequest();

            /// `localPath` is get from Web.Config.
            string localPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileServiceLocalPath"]);

            string root = localPath + "\\" + model.StorageName;

            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(root);
            var stream = new MemoryStream(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);

            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StreamContent(stream)
            };

            response.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/"+ model.Extension);

            IHttpActionResult result = ResponseMessage(response);

            return result;
        }
    }
```

File Service

```
public interface IFileService
    {
        Task SendCloud(IList<FileDto> modelList, string localPath);
    }   

    public class FileService : IFileService
    {
        public Task SendCloud(IList<FileDto> modelList,string localPath)
        {
            /// `ftpUserName`, `ftpPassword` and `storagePath` is get from Web.Config.
            string ftpUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpUserName"];
            string ftpPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpPassword"];
            string storagePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileServiceStoragePath"];

            /// Uploaded files are sent to the cloud server.
            foreach (var model in modelList)
            {
                FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(storagePath + model.StorageName);

                req.UseBinary = true;
                req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserName, ftpPassword);
                byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(localPath + "\\" + model.StorageName);
                req.ContentLength = fileData.Length;

                Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
                reqStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                reqStream.Close();
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

    }
```

It's image for build.

[image: Image review request for fiddler]

[image: Response]

Comment: It would make sense if you add some explanation with your answer as well. Perhaps, what or how is it achieving the goal. Where is the token being sent? And isn't this FTP? I do not require any username/passwords but the token that is used to authenticate and then upload the files.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `HttpClient` with `MultipartFormDataContent` approach should work

just need to look out for input names, please try the following

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

string filename = @"E:\Uploads\demo.csv"
    , filename2 = @"E:\Uploads\demo2.csv"
    , url = "http://demo.schooling.net/school/attendance"
    , token = "fe60313b0edfdfaf757f9744815454545"
    ;
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);


// Keep `token` here, no quote escaping
form.Add(new StringContent(token), "token");

// Keep `Files[]` here
form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(bytes), "Files[]", Path.GetFileName(filename));

// To add 2nd file, keep the input name as `Files[]`
bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename2);
form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(bytes), "Files[]", Path.GetFileName(filename2));        

var result = httpClient.PostAsync(url, form).Result;
```

Comment: As expected, this redirects to the login page. (since no token authentication was accepted)

Comment: since the `token` is a constant, anyone could upload the file. Does server maintain a whitelist of IPs?

Comment: I will get that checked. And the snippet above would take a single file not all the files placed in the directory, right?

Comment: pardon me, but that is one ugly way to do it. Imagine if I have a hundred files or a thousands of them? Perhaps a way to read all the files in the directory and then store their paths to an array which can be used to upload to the server?

Comment: hmm...my code was a demonstration of **how to** send multiple files.
Whether you've got thousands of files, it's up to you to turn it into a simple **for** loop